# Possible recording interruptions in atop

Tags: linux, system-administration

I am writing a program that would analyze dumps of system activity so I need to know about all the possible interruptions in the records. I read the atop man page but there was no information about it. Are there any other recording interruptions in **atop** (except .....logging restarted....)?

Here is atopsar example output of (....logging restarted....):

[image: Here is an example of logging interruption]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any other interruptions in atopsar. But when I looked at the atop program code, I found some possible errors that can appear.

Hope it helped someone.

[Possible errors from atop program (open source) code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8dkL.png)